# swapping two records not working: I get "Call to a member function save() on null" error

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7

I need to swap 2 records. I tried with this code, but it doesn't work (`info` is a one-to-one relationship):

```
$tmp = $from->info;
$from->info = $to->info;
$from->info->save();
$to->info = $tmp;
$to->info->save();
```

I get the error in last line, cause `$to->info` is null.

Comment: Where is `$to` initialized?

Comment: You can debug by dumping your var $to with `var_dump($to)` and see if it's empty

Comment: Doesn't $resultFrom have to be $from?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$tmp1 = $from->info;
$tmp2 = $to->info;
$from->info = $tmp2;
$from->info->save();
$to->info = $tmp1;
$to->info->save();
```